# String.Format with SelectMany

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda

I want to set an String in one Line with help of `.SelectMany()`.
I have an `Object`, which holds an `Dictionary<String,FileInfo>`. For each element into these Dictionary I want to got the Key to put into String.Format(), but i always get `"System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__142[System.String,System.Char]"` as returnvalue.

Where is my fault?

```
String.Format(
    "All Strings : {0} on {1} ", 
    MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x), 
    MyObject.Type);
```

Comment: replace `MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x)` with `string,Join(" ", MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x))`

Comment: Could you please show us the definition of the Dictionary and the example of desired output format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectMany will return an IEnumerable, that's why, you'll need to get the keys into a string, like so:

```
String.Format("All Strings : {0} on {1}",
     String.Join(", ", MyObject.MyDictionary.Select(x => x.Key)),
     MyObject.Type);
```

Answer (score 2):

framework 3.5

```
 String.Format(
        "All Strings : {0} on {1} ", 
        string.Join(string.Empty, MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray()),  
        MyObject.Type);
```

framework 4

```
 String.Format(
        "All Strings : {0} on {1} ", 
        string.Join(string.Empty, MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x)),  
        MyObject.Type);
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but if I use String.Format("All Strings : {0} on {1} ", string.Join(";", MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray()), MyObject.Type); I got : C;o;n;t;e;n;t;1;C;o;n;t;e;n;t;2; ...

Comment: Edit made, without specifying the first argument of string.Join, you should have the output corrected

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot to all, I solved it now with that way :

```
String.Format("All Strings : {0} on {1} ", String.Join("; ",MyObject.MyDictionary.Keys), MyObject.Type);
```